# Custom command / target run only for default build not install

Tags: cmake

I want to build my documentation (doxygen) alongside my project with CMake by default.  I let CMake generate Makefiles.  I know of these approaches so far:

1)

```
add_custom_target(doc ALL
  COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_COMMAND})
```

2)

```
add_custom_command(
  TARGET my-executable
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_COMMAND})
```

The issue I have with the first approach is that the target is build *both* during build and install (i.e. when running `make` *and* when running `make install`).  This is a no-go.

The issue with the second approach is that it is not actually correct:  the documentation *doesn't* have to be built after the executable (in fact, it can be done in parallel even).  Moreover I cannot build *only* the executable now.

**Is there a way to create this custom command / target such that it is run *only* during `make` (building) and not during `make install` (installing) but independently from other targets such as executables?**

Basically I'd need a "default target".  Also I really want to avoid having to execute CMake recursively or make directly.

Comment: Use `add_custom_command(OUTPUT ...)` to define a rule to produce the documentation and `add_custom_target(... ALL)` that depends on command's output. This way the docs would be built only once.

Comment: @arrowd: Problem with non-default custom target is that its files **cannot be installed**: (in CMake documentation files, denoted for installation but not produced by `make all`, are referred as *undefined behavior*). But documentation files are usually intended for installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create a file, which existence means that documentation file have been built:

```
set(documentation_file ${CMAKE__BINARY_DIR}/docs_ready)

# Documentation target
add_custom_target(docs ALL DEPENDS ${documentation_file})
# Documentation command
add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${documentation_file}
    COMMAND ${DOXYGEN_COMMAND}
    # And mark that documentation is created
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E touch ${documentation_file}
)
```

Comment: Only drawback: `make docs` run manually doesn't rebuild the documentation now (because `${documentation_file}` is there, ofc).  Adding an answer with a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

The solution given by [@Tsyvarev](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49085149/1116364) works perfectly *except* for one issue:

Running `make docs` manually doesn't cause a re-build of the documentation because the "output file" `${documentation_file}` is always considered up to date (there are no dependencies specified that could be newer).

Three workarounds I found:

- Run `make -B docs`.  The `-B` flags causes GNU Make to consider all targets out of date, and thus causes the documentation to be build.
- Add a "manual docs" target which depends on first a `docs-clean` target which removes `${documentation_file}` and then on `docs` itself (to build the documentation and the file), and run `make docs-manual`:

  ```
  add_custom_target(docs-clean
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove ${documentation_file})
  add_custom_target(docs-manual)
  add_dependencies(docs-manual docs-clean docs)
  ```

  Note that I fear that this is just a dirty hack: AFAIK the order in which the dependencies (`docs-clean` and `docs`) are build isn't specified, and as they don't have a dependency between them, they could even be built in parallel.

  Using `add_custom_command` with a `TARGET docs-manual` and `PRE_BUILD` (which runs the command before building dependencies) instead of the `docs-clean` target would've been perfect, but this [only works for Visual Studio 7 or later](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/add_custom_command.html).
- Add a custom target that depends on `docs` but removes the generated `${documentation_file}`:

  ```
  add_custom_target(docs-manual
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E remove ${documentation_file})
  add_dependencies(docs-manual docs)
  ```

  This works except for when running it the first time after a `make docs`, because then the generated file will still be there when `docs` is built.

*edit: Use `add_dependencies` instead of `DEPENDS` of `add_custom_target` because the later is only intended for files, not for dependencies on targets.*

Comment: In `add_custom_target` command *DEPENDS* adds dependency not from a *target*, as you expect, but from a *file*. Anywhere, approach with cleaning documentation file has same drawback as the second approach in the question post: on `make install` the documentation will be built too.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thanks, fixed the issue with the `DEPENDS`.  Cleaning the documentation file only happens when the `docs-manual` target is (manually) run.  Running `make` followed by `make install` builds the documentation only once (because the `docs` target alone *doesn't* remove the documentation file).

Comment: Having `docs-manual` and `docs` seems a bit messy, but OK. BTW, in case of documentation files produces by doxygen, list *source* files can be easily grabbed (e.g. via `file(GLOB)`). So, *DEPENDS* option for "documentation file" allows you to rebuild the documentation only when its content could be changed. This way seems more clear for me, than additional `docs-manual` target.